# Which approach is better - CASE WHEN or DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle

For some simple logical tests the same functionality can be achieved with CASE WHEN and DECODE syntax. What approach is better here (argumentation/measurement needed)?

```
SUM(CASE WHEN xyz=100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

or

```
SUM(DECODE(xyz,100,1,0))
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN` is standard SQL, `DECODE` is not. So I use `CASE WHEN` as to have my queries as readable and maintainable as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I stumbled upon this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1112467?tstart=0

"The performance difference is so slight that it makes very little sense in using that as primary criteria for whether to use CASE or DECODE. So unless you're calling this statement from a very tight loop doing millions of iterations, the decision should rather be which one, CASE or DECODE, best suits the need."